# Creating a Rails API for private and public use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have searched for this answer but haven't found anything and need help with the concept. So, we created an API with rails which feeds our Angular web app (separate server) and our iphone app. Currently people login through the form and devise from the api sends an auth_token for future interaction, the data is also secured using AWS keys.

Now we want to open up the API to the public, but only on certain subscription plans and maybe only part of the functionality. We want to use authentication similar to Pingdom were a user on the correct plan generates an api token within their account and sends this token with the request. This is where i'm at a bit of a loss, because if i secure the controllers of the API for some users who authenticate by token then this will effect the iphone and web app users too who don't have an api token?

I can not get my head around the concept of a private API which is available to some users if they have an api key. Please help.

Comment: I'd create an api for external consumers and keep the internal api separate serving your apps independently. Because when you open an api you're nit free to change responses anymore

Answer (score 0):

It may help to think of your private and public APIs as not-necessarily-compatible versions of the same API. It's the same principle as introducing a v2 API that breaks backwards compatibility with v1, but needing to support both versions.

Obviously you wouldn't want your internal API to share a version numbering sequence with your external one. But there are various gems that will help you with handling versioned APIs, and that could include differences in authentication methods.

So the API that's available to your users could look, to them, like it's the **only** API available. It could have its own version numbering system, so that if you decide to introduce v2 of your public API you can. But the same system that maintains that API could do something similar for your "internal" API, ensuring that its endpoints are separate from the public ones, but allowing you to share common code between public and private implementations in the same way that a v1 and v2 API might share some code but would also have differences.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Hmmmm i'm not sure i would want my team to maintain two sets of routes that do exactly the same thing. So if we introduce oauth2 for example, which requires a user to create an application within their admin panel, how does the Angular web app and iphone app bypass having to authenticate through an oauth client to pull the logged in users information? as the routes will be protected by the oauth key and some users won't have set up the credentials?